# Job titles related to real estate

Tags: single-word-requests

I would first like to thank anyone who might pay attention and provide an answer to this question, as I'm new at the community.

I work in a real state agency, and we deal with all kinds of transactions, like buying and selling, leasing, and management of condominiums (like dealing with the landlords and such, arranging polls for changes or fixes in a building, etc).

What's confusing is the specific job title for the various kinds of jobs we have here.

As an example, my specific function is to deal with lessees who are vacating the apartments or houses.

So, my question is the job titles of these sectors:

1)The agents that finds owners of real estate, like apartments, and convince them to let the agency to manage the leasing. I believe it's a leasing agent.

2)Same as above, but for buying and selling of real state. I believe they are real state brokers.

3)The people who work at administrative functions inside a real state agency, like a)those in charge of the vacancy of leased real state (me), b) those in charge of managing the leasing paperwork, and c) those in charge of the condominium management (dealing with apartment managers and landlords).

Comment: Are you in the US, UK, or elsewhere?

Comment: Thank you for your attention, @MarkBeadles . As in the post below, I would like to know the titles used in the US.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as it is too narrowly focused for ELU (real estate jargon), is still a matter of opinion (UK and US usages, and doubtless others, are at variance) and is best researched in a suitable establishment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common job title for this type of work is in fact, Lettings Administrator, and the title could equally well refer to parts 3. (a) , (b) and (c) in your question.

If you want to be specific, the job function you describe in part (c) "Those in charge of the condominium management (dealing with apartment managers and landlords)" is often the remit of a 'property manager', but as you can see from the second example below, the titles 'lettings administrator' and 'property manager' are often used interchangeably in this context.

Job description from reed jobs board for [Lettings Administrator](https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/lettings-administrator/31540120#/jobs/lettings-administrator):-

> Key Duties:
>
> 1. Providing administrative support to the Lettings and Allocations team
> 2. Preparing Pre and Post-Tenancy agreements and start up packs.
> 3. Assisting with viewings
> 4. Dealing with the portfolio of market rent properties

Here is another from indeed for a '[Lettings Administrator /
Property Manager](https://www.indeed.co.uk/cmp/Square-Quarters/jobs/Letting-Administrator-c12f09473e6e8ea8?sjdu=QwrRXKrqZ3CNX5W-O9jEvfeJp5UDoxjP1RAD5zMfu7JkWQd0Jre8YLkAeN4IQVw6HI7XgMnmzn-gtADoJMEYkMKF6dHmvsB4REW5oZAz50qbyPI7hSrXrFGa6PoRW4r8)'

> Core Duties
>
> Process rent payments, ensure all rents are entered into our property
>   management system and produce month-end Landlord statements
>
> Tenant referencing  Act as Property Manager, responsible for all
>   aspects of letting and management of a small property portfolio
>
> Provide support to the Directors
>
> Answering telephone calls and dealing with email enquiries
>
> General office admin duties
>
> Tenancy contract preparation
>
> Organise and maintain the office filing system
>
> Ensure that our invoicing and receipts systems are a ‘dream’ for our
>   bookkeeper
>
> Enter data on the in-house database system
>
> Chase late rent payments, by phone and process payments by
>   credit/debit card
>
> Manage annual rent reviews and renewals

**Lettings Administrator** works well for the various functions you've described in part 3 of your question.

Both 'Lettings Administrator' and 'Property Manager' are used in the UK. In the USA 'Property Manager' is the more usual term, for example here is [a job description](http://jobview.monster.com/property-administrator-job-lombard-il-us-181044504.aspx?mescoid=1100052001001&jobPosition=3) for a US based vacancy: -

> Property Administrator
>
> Exciting new opportunity with one of Chicago's largest Real Estate
>   Investment and Management Firms! They have an opening for a property
>   administrator... This role will aid in:
>   Maintaining relationships with tenants, 
>   Aiding in accounting,
>   Preparing and forecasting budgets, and 
>   Supporting the overall management of the building.
>
> Responsibilities include:
>
> 1. Handling tenant requests,
> 2. Schedule appointments,
> 3. Maintain office supplies,
> 4. Assist with tenant events for the building...

Comment: This works for the UK, but in the US they use an entirely different set of titles.

Comment: You may please provide the US equivalent also.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Gary . It's a very clear explanation of what the job title comprises, so this is the definitive answer for British-english. As Mark Beadles pointed out that these terms can be different in the US, I would also like to know what they are.

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding US, I've amended my answer towards the end to clarify